# How to prove a specific relation of the type $\left[\hat{V}, \hat{V}^{\dagger}\right]=0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics

I have the operators

$\hat{V}=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j+1}, \qquad \hat{V}^{\dagger} = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j}$,

where $\hat{a}_{j} \; (\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger})$ is the bosonic annihilation (creation) operator and $j$ is a subscript running from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I want to proof the commutation relation $\left[\hat{V}, \hat{V}^{\dagger}\right]=0$; therefore

$\left[\hat{V}, \hat{V}^{\dagger}\right]=\sum_{j,j'}\left[(\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j+1})(\hat{a}_{j'+1}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j'})-(\hat{a}_{j'+1}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j'})(\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j+1})\right],$

where I have the double sum to consider the different labels for $j$; then, the above sum can be broken in the terms for which $j=j'$ and $j\neq j'$, that is,

$\left[\hat{V}, \hat{V}^{\dagger}\right]=\sum_{j}\left[(\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j+1})(\hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j})-(\hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j})(\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j+1})\right] +\sum_{j \neq j'}\left[(\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j+1})(\hat{a}_{j'+1}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j'})-(\hat{a}_{j'+1}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j'})(\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j+1})\right] $

$=\sum_{j}(\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j+1})(\hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j})-(\hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j})(\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \, \hat{a}_{j+1})$,

where we have use the fact that $\left[\hat{a}_{j}, \hat{a}_{j'}^{\dagger} \right]=\left[\hat{a}_{j}, \hat{a}_{j'} \right]=\left[\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger}, \hat{a}_{j'}^{\dagger} \right]=0 \; \text{for} j\neq j'$, and therefore, all bosonic operators commute, hence the respective sum can be made 0. However how can I proof that the last sum in above equation is also 0, in order to satisfy the commutation relation  $\left[\hat{V}, \hat{V}^{\dagger}\right]=0?$

Answer (score 1):

Well, let $\hat{n}_j = \hat{a}^{\dagger}_j\hat{a}_j$ be the number operator, and remember the commutation relations, the only non vanishing being:
$$
\left[ \hat{a}_i , \hat{a}_j^{\dagger}\right] = \delta_{ij},
$$

Now let's use this to work the first term to write it in terms of the number operators. First of all, swap $\hat{a}_j^{\dagger}$ and bring it in the third position from the left, then use the commutation relation to introduce $\hat{n}_{j+1}$:
$$
\hat{a}_j^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{j+1}\hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{j} = \\
\hat{a}_{j+1}\hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_j^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{j}  \\
\left( 1 - \hat{n}_{j+1} \right) \hat{n}_j = \\
\hat{n}_{j} - \hat{n}_{j+1} \hat{n}_{j}  .
$$
Let's now do the same for the other term
$$
\hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{j}\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{j+1} = \\
\hat{a}_{j}\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{j+1}^{\dagger}  \hat{a}_{j+1} =\\
\left(1 - \hat{n}_j \right)\hat{n}_{j+1} = \\
\hat{n}_{j+1} - \hat{n}_{j}\hat{n}_{j+1}  
$$

Now we have to do the sum over $j$ of the difference of these terms. Notice that $\sum_j \hat{n}_j = \sum_j \hat{n}_{j+1}$ (just relabel the dummy index $j$), and therefore you are left with:
$$
\sum_j \left[ \hat{n}_{j} , \hat{n}_{j+1}  \right] = 0
$$
which vanishes simply because $ \left[ \hat{n}_{j} , \hat{n}_{j+1}  \right] = 0$ for all $j$ (simple exercise, you can check it using the commutation relations)

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful relation for commutators of products. It's quite easy to derive if you write out the product and add 0 (i.e add and take away the same term). It's 
$[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$ there's also $[A,BC]=B[A,C]+[A,B]C$ or you can just flip the first one and take the negative. There's a similar identity relating anti-commutators and commutators too